# how can I add styling for vertical space between these elements?

Tags: react-native

I'm creating a new Login page in RN.  All of the components below are stacked nicely and symmetrically in the View.  However, I'd like to include some space between the components.  What would be the easiest and most proper way to do that based on the layout and style shown below?:

```
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <TextInput placeholder="Email" />
    <TextInput placeholder="Password" />
    <Button title="TEST"></Button>
  </View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  textInput: {
    height: 40,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The most basic and simple way is to give `Margin` values between components.

> **margin**
>
> Setting margin has the same effect as setting each of `marginTop`,
>   `marginLeft`, `marginBottom`, and `marginRight`. See
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin for more
>   details.

**Usage**

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
       <View style={styles.container}>
    <TextInput style={styles.textInput} placeholder="Email" />
    <TextInput style={styles.textInput} placeholder="Password" />
    <Button title="TEST"></Button>
  </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  textInput: {
    height: 40,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderWidth: 1,
    margin: 20
  },
});
```

[image]